# Gravity Stripe: how to make payment for several periods of subscription

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I am using Grvity Forms with Stripe Add-on
I need to create a monthly subscription, but first payment should be for 3 months, so user buyes 3 months at once ($300), and then after 3 months he will be charged $100/month.
How to create such Stripe feed?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, I've resolved it in such way:
I've placed in the form separate product item with type "Singe Product" and price $300. Then in the Stripe feed configured subscription with trial for 90 days. Subscription linked to main product item (subscription for $100), and turned on Setup Fee, linked to the second product component ($300).
You probably need to hide Total section in the form, because it will show $400 as a sum of both products, but Stripe charges only $300 and creates subscription $100/month with trial.